# Filter logs with grok in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am trying to filter out logs received with the help of grok. Below is the sample log

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2013/04/05 01:08:47.048 | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-2443-ProcessTask [31111111112]] [b2cConfirmationAction] CRON JOB ID : 101AA1C, ACTION : ConfirmationAction , CUSTOMER ID : 000001111111 , EMAIL ADDRESS : abc@gmail.com , SCHEDULE : Every 1 week  , MESSAGE : Execution started for action ConfirmationAction
```

I am using grok debugger (https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to test before updating logstash conf file.
Below is my filter code :

```
%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{GREEDYDATA:greedydata}%{SPACE}%{YEAR}[/-]%{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}%{GREEDYDATA:gd} \[(?:%{WORD:action})\]%{GREEDYDATA:cronjobresult}
```

Here I am getting outpout as

```
"level": [ [ "INFO" ] ], "greedydata": [ [ " | jvm 1 | main | 20" ] ], "SPACE": [ [ "", " " ] ], "YEAR": [ [ "13" ] ], "MONTHNUM": [ [ "04" ] ], "MONTHDAY": [ [ "05" ] ], "HOUR": [ [ "01" ] ], "MINUTE": [ [ "08" ] ], "SECOND": [ [ "47.048" ] ], "gd": [ [ " | \u001b[m\u001b[32mINFO [TaskExecutor-master-2443-ProcessTask [31111111112]]" ] ], "action": [ [ "b2cConfirmationAction" ] ], "cronjobresult": [ [ " CRON JOB ID : 101AA4A , ACTION : ConfirmationAction , CUSTOMER ID : 000001111111 , EMAIL ADDRESS : abc@gmail.com , SCHEDULE : Every 1 week , MESSAGE : Execution started for action ConfirmationAction" ] ] }
```

My requirement is to get values under cronjobresult like cron job iD customer id with different and independent field so that I can use these values in kibana. Right now I am not able to get it. Also I have used greedyData twice, better approach for this log would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply extend your filter further and match it explicitly. For instance, to match cron job id, you can write `CRON JOB ID : %{BASE16NUM:Cron_job_id}` in your filter.

If you do not need any data from log then you can simply write `.*` instead of `GREEDYDATA` and it will be skipped.

Here is the complete filter for your log,

```
%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{GREEDYDATA:greedydata}%{SPACE}%{YEAR}[/-]%{MONTHNUM}[/-]%{MONTHDAY}%{SPACE}%{HOUR}:%{MINUTE}:%{SECOND}%{GREEDYDATA:gd} \[(?:%{WORD:action})\] CRON JOB ID : %{BASE16NUM:Cron_job_id},.*CUSTOMER ID : %{NUMBER:Customer_id}.*EMAIL ADDRESS : %{EMAILADDRESS}.*SCHEDULE : %{GREEDYDATA:schedule}.*, MESSAGE : %{GREEDYDATA:Message}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "level": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "greedydata": [
    [
      "   | jvm 1    | main    | 20"
    ]
  ],
  "SPACE": [
    [
      "",
      " "
    ]
  ],
  "YEAR": [
    [
      "13"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHNUM": [
    [
      "04"
    ]
  ],
  "MONTHDAY": [
    [
      "05"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "01"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "08"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "47.048"
    ]
  ],
  "gd": [
    [
      " | [m[32mINFO  [TaskExecutor-master-2443-ProcessTask [31111111112]]"
    ]
  ],
  "action": [
    [
      "b2cConfirmationAction"
    ]
  ],
  "Cron_job_id": [
    [
      "101AA1C"
    ]
  ],
  "Customer_id": [
    [
      "000001111111"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "000001111111"
    ]
  ],
  "EMAILADDRESS": [
    [
      "abc@gmail.com"
    ]
  ],
  "local": [
    [
      "abc"
    ]
  ],
  "remote": [
    [
      "gmail.com"
    ]
  ],
  "schedule": [
    [
      "Every 1 week  "
    ]
  ],
  "Message": [
    [
      "Execution started for action"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Please note that I have used `EMAILADDRESS` pattern from, https://github.com/rgevaert/grok-patterns/blob/master/grok.d/postfix_patterns

If you want to test it on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com, you need to add,

```
EMAILADDRESSPART [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-=:]+
EMAILADDRESS %{EMAILADDRESSPART:local}@%{EMAILADDRESSPART:remote}
```

as cusomtom patterns by checking `add custom patterns`